# How to skip a row from sql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web

Hi novice to php and mysql. Trying to find how to skip first or last value in a loop of my sql table in descending order? I want to display recently added rows first but not display the last added row.

```
<tr>
<?php
    $page=$_GET['pages'];    /* created in index.php(pages.php?pages=m_$title) */
    $nage="z_".$page;
    $query="SELECT * FROM `$nage` ORDER BY a_id DESC LIMIT 0, 1" ;
    $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
        $page_title=$row['title'];
        $img_src=$row['img_src'];

        // $page_desc=$row['story'];

        echo  "<tr bgcolor='pink'>
                   <td style='width:40%'>
                       <div class='titleDivX'>
                           <img class='imgFrame'src='$img_src' alt='tasvir'/>
                           <h5> $page_title</h5>
                       </div>
                   </td>
                   <td bgcolor='yellow'>
                       <div class='titleDivX'> </div>
                   </td>
               </tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: get the count before you start, and have an `if` block inside the `while`?

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array advances the pointer, so you could just call `mysqli_fetch_array($run)` once before the while loop.

Comment: You are only returning ONE row `LIMIT 0, 1`. So what are you trying to skip. The first row and the last row are the ONLY ROW. **Save time throw the script away**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because The Question and the provided code make no sence when seen together

Comment: judy that is way over the top. We don't need that sort of language here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `mysqli_num_rows` function described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php). If you want to find the first or the last row then you can replace this part of your code

```
$run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
```

with this

```
$run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$rowsCount=mysqli_num_rows($run);
$count = 0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
    $count++;       
    $isFirst = ($count == 1) ? true : false;
    $isLast = ($count == $rowsCount) ? true : false;
```

Then you can use the `$isFirst` and `$isLast` variables for the IF statement. For example if you want to skip the last row then you can use a code like this:

```
<?php
    $page=$_GET['pages'];    /* created in index.php(pages.php?pages=m_$title) */
    $nage="z_".$page;
    $query="SELECT * FROM `$nage` ORDER BY a_id DESC LIMIT 0, 1" ;
    $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $rowsCount=mysqli_num_rows($run);
    $count = 0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
        $count++;       
        $isFirst = ($count == 1) ? true : false;
        $isLast = ($count == $rowsCount) ? true : false;

        if (!$isLast) {
            $page_title=$row['title'];
            $img_src=$row['img_src'];

            // $page_desc=$row['story'];

            echo  "<tr bgcolor='pink'>
                       <td style='width:40%'>
                           <div class='titleDivX'>
                               <img class='imgFrame'src='$img_src' alt='tasvir'/>
                               <h5> $page_title</h5>
                           </div>
                       </td>
                       <td bgcolor='yellow'>
                           <div class='titleDivX'> </div>
                       </td>
                   </tr>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Instead of `$isFirst = ...` and `$isLast = ...`, you can simply do this `if($count == 1 || $count == $rowsCount) continue;` to optimize your code further.

Comment: Also, given your current code, `if (!$isLast) { ...` should be `if (!$isFirst && !$isLast) { ...`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Yes, your are right, but I wanted to show what is first and what is last using names for educational purpose.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul My code with `if (!$isLast)` is correct. Look at the question (first or last) and description of my example _For example if you want to skip **the last row** then you can use a code like this_

Comment: Oh, my bad, I thought it's *first **and** last value*. Your answer pretty much wrapped up every aspect of the question, +1 from me. :-)

Comment: `LIMIT 0, 1` The first row is the last row is the only row. Save time and CPU cycles, throw the script away. Tempted to DV but resisted the urge